# f:ajax firing only once

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a a form loading a list from my database. I can update, and delete the row i select and that is working fine. Now I added a start and stop button to each row to enable start an engine from another application. Now what I want to do is when i click on start ,my engine would start based on that row and that row would hide the start button and show the stop button.

I have implemented ajax on those columns in the row but it updates all rows at once and the ajax only triggers once.

What am I doing wrong here and can you show me the best way to press on start and then hide my start-button and show my stop-button or press on stop and hide my stop-button and show my start-button on that particular row.

snippet of codes in my managedbean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HibernateController {
    private ArrayList<IPAddress> ipAddresses;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    private boolean isStarted = false;
    private boolean isStopped = true;

public HibernateController(){
        ipAddresses = new ArrayList<IPAddress>();
    }


public boolean engineIsStarted() {

        return isStopped;

    }

    public boolean engineIsStopped() {
        return isStarted;
    }

    public void startEngine(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        System.out.println("I am here and started");
        isStarted = true;
        isStopped = false;
    }

    public void stopEngine(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        System.out.println("I am here and stopped");
        isStopped = true;
        isStarted = false;
    }
```

Snippet of codes in my xhtml

```
<h:form>

        <h:dataTable value="#{hibernateController.ipAddresses}" var="tempAddress"
            styleClass="demo-table" 
            headerClass="demo-table-header"
            rowClasses="demo-table-odd-row,demo-table-even-row">

            <h:column>
                <!-- the column header -->
                <f:facet name="header">IP Adress</f:facet>

                <!--  the value for each row -->
                #{tempAddress.ipAddress}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <!-- the column header -->
                <f:facet name="header">Port Number</f:facet>

                <!--  the value for each row -->
                #{tempAddress.portNumber}
            </h:column>



            <h:column>
                <!-- the column header -->
                <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>

                 <!-- the value for each row -->
                <h:commandLink value="Update"
                    action="#{hibernateController.loadAddress(tempAddress.id)}"/>
                |

                <h:commandLink value="Delete"
                    onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this address?')) return false"
                    action="#{hibernateController.deleteAddress(tempAddress.id)}"/>

            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <h:commandButton id="startButton" value="start" rendered="#{hibernateController.engineIsStarted()}">
                    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" listener="#{hibernateController.startEngine}" render="@all" />
                </h:commandButton>

                <h:commandButton id="stopButton" value="stop" rendered="#{hibernateController.engineIsStopped()}">
                     <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" listener="#{hibernateController.stopEngine}" render="@all" />
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:column> 

        </h:dataTable>

        </h:form>
```

[Image of interface now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cWpK.png)

Comment: Tried using a different value for the `render="@all"`? Looks a bit to broad/wide

Comment: Use for example render=@form instead Of All